# When and How do pacemaker cells develop during the cell aggregation process of Dictyostelium discoideum?

Tags: microbiology, cell-signaling, communication

I was reading a paper by [Tang & Othmer](http://www.math.umn.edu/~othmer/papers/Tang:1995:EOW.pdf) about oscillations and waves in *Dictyostelium discoideum*. Under certain condition like starvation period in the life cycle of a *Dictyostelium discoideum* community, they evolve itself into a multicellular organism in a process of cellular aggregation. I have read about *Pacemaker* cells among these individuals which transmits periodic *cAMP* and attracts other cells towards them.

**So I was wondering: When and How do these Pacemaker cells develop from a "normal" cell into a pacemaker cell excreting cAMP?**

References, links or answers would be very helpful for me.

Comment: What exactly do you mean: 1) How are they are evolving (into the next coming million years?); 2) How did they evolve (in the last couple of million years?) or 3) How they come into being in a micro environment like an erlenmeyer flask with cAMP floating around (wax and waning effect in a few hours time)?

Comment: AliceD : By evolving, I mean how do some cells "become" Pacemakers.

Comment: Thanks. I have linked that same article again you linked before, as it is the same literature you are referring to am I right?

Comment: @AliceD : Done. I have attached the paper.

Comment: We were working on it simultaneously: all good :) Thanks! +1

Comment: Yes, this happened twice now.